# Compute this complex integeration

Tags: complex-analysis

Compute 
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{1+z^2}$$
where $\gamma$ is a rectifiable curve from $o$ to $1$,  which does not pass through $\pm i$.

Comment: It depends on how many times the curve winds around $i$ and around $-i$, and in which direction (clockwise or counterclockwise) as the curve goes from $0$ to $1$.  It would be one  of the multiple values of the arctangent function. (I'm assuming you meant $dz/(1+z^2)$ rather than $dx/(1+z^2)$.  If not, my comment above does not apply.)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have correct the mistake

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Perhaps "does not pass through $\pm i$" means "does not cross the line from $+i$ to $-i$".
$$
\frac1{1+z^2}=\frac1{2i}\left(\frac1{z-i}-\frac1{z+i}\right)
$$
If $\gamma$ does not cross the line from $+i$ to $-i$, then $\gamma$ circles $+i$ and $-i$ the same number of times and the residues at $z=+i$, $\frac1{2i}$, and $z=-i$, $-\frac1{2i}$, cancel each other.

Comment: Thanks! As Michael Hardy says, multiple values is the key